# how to setup jsfiddle for react

Tags: reactjs, jsfiddle

I am new to jsFiddle and tried to do some react coding at jsfiddle

```
(https://jsfiddle.net/coolshare/8ndvgaxd/1/)
```

I have included react.js and react-dom.js as external resources.
I got "Bad JSFiddle configuration, please fork the original Rect JSFiddle"

What did I miss?

thanks

Comment: I find it easier to use service like https://www.webpackbin.com/ for trying out react because of support of modules

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it at:

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/coolshare/8ndvgaxd/21/]
```

by making sure all the required import is listed at the "External Resources"